# Selected Value from DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to get the selected value from a dropdownlist which is populated from a database.  The list populates fine and allows me to select a value, but when I click the submit button, I get an error that the list "is not set to instance of an object"

Here is my view:

```
@model LoanRequestRowViewModel

<h2>CreateTest</h2>
<div>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>
            <span class="inline-block">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoanPurpose)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LoanPurposeId, Model.LoanPurpose)

            </span>

            <span class="inline-block">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AmountRequested)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AmountRequested)
            </span>
            <span class="inline-block">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestedRate, new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestedRate, new { @class = "inputROW" })
            </span>

        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("CreateTest")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateTest()
        {
            var loanPurposes = await GetLoanPurposes();


            var model = new LoanRequestRowViewModel();

            model.LoanPurpose.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-Please Select-", Value = "-1" });
            foreach (var purpose in loanPurposes)
            {
                model.LoanPurpose.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = purpose.Value.ToString(),
                    Text = purpose.Text.ToString()
                });
            }

            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("CreateTest")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateTest(LoanRequestRowViewModel model)
        {
            var newLoan = new LoanRequest()
            {
                AmountRequested = model.AmountRequested,
                LoanPurposeId = model.LoanPurposeId
            };

            return View();
        }
```

Here is the Model:

```
public class LoanRequestRowViewModel
    {
        public LoanRequestRowViewModel()
        {
            LoanClasses = new List<SelectListItem>();
            LoanTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
            LoanPurpose = new List<SelectListItem>();
            RateIndex = new List<SelectListItem>();
            PaymentPeriod = new List<SelectListItem>();
            PaymentType = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Guid LoanApplicationId { get; set; }

        public Guid LoanPurposeId { get; set; }
        public Guid LoanClassId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Loan Class")]
        public IList<SelectListItem> LoanClasses { get; set; }

        public string SelectedLoanClass { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Loan Purpose")]
        public IList<SelectListItem> LoanPurpose { get; set; }


        public string SelectedLoanPurpose { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amount Requested")]
        public decimal? AmountRequested { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Requested Rate")]
        public decimal? RequestedRate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Loan Type")]
        public IList<SelectListItem> LoanTypes { get; set; }



        public string SelectedLoanType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Rate Index")]
        public IList<SelectListItem> RateIndex { get; set; }

        public Guid SelectedRateIndex { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Origination Fee")]
        public decimal? OriginationFeePercentage { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Variable Rate Margin")]
        public decimal? VariableRateMargin { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Variable Rate Floor")]
        public decimal? VariableRateFloor { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Variable Rate Ceiling")]
        public decimal? VariableRateCeiling { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Payment Type")]
        public IList<SelectListItem> PaymentType { get; set; }


        public string SelectedPaymentType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Payment Period")]
        public IList<SelectListItem> PaymentPeriod { get; set; }


        public int? SelectedPaymentPeriod { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Number of Payments")]
        public int? NumberOfPayments { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Amortization Term")]
        public decimal? AmortizationTerm { get; set; }
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your model and the property you get the error for?

Comment: Could you have the error in the view? In your post method you are returning the View again, without passing a model instance (So the model instance will be null)

Comment: @DanielJ.G. is right. It is the problem in view. Please pass the model to view.

Comment: I just did return View() so the code would compile.  It never hits that line because as soon as the submit button is clicked it throws the error on the dropdownlist in the View.

Answer (score 0):

At your view you are expecting an viewmodel with information but you returning nothing to the view.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LoanPurposeId, Model.LoanPurpose)
```

Asks for a filled list of loan purposes.

But because the model is null, it simply crashes.

To solve this problem you need to pass a new instance of the model: LoanRequestRowViewModel

Also i would take to consideration to rename: Model.LoanPurpose. It sounds to me that it just returns one property, not a list of items.

Comment: I cannot rename any of the models, in any case, I appreciate your help.  The problem was the fact that the LoanPurposeId is a Guid.  I used the "SelectedPurposeId" which is a string, and now everything works fine.  Go figure.